# Having jQuery operate on non-existing divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want jQuery to operate on **Divs that don't exist when the page is loaded** ; the divs are created on the fly following client's actions (i.e. AFTER the page is loaded).

Below is some very simple code to illustrate the point:

#### HTML Code

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded"> Click here </div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery Code

```
<script>
    $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',function(){
        var s = '<div id="DivCreatedOnTheFly">New Stuff</div>'  ;
        $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append(s);
        // Code below works fine as expected, 
        // but is nested and is hard to read / debug
        // $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").on('click', 
        //   function(){alert("Click On New Stuff");});
    });

    // The code below fails, 
    // it operate on $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly"), 
    // that doesn't exist when the page is loaded

    $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").on('click',function(event){alert("Click On New Stuff");}); 
</script>
```

When the user clicks on "click here", a new Div is appended. When the user clicks on the new Div, the user receives an alert message.

If the alert message is nested in the `$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded")` code, it works as expected , but gets harder to read and debug.

If the alert message is written in code related to `$("#DivCreatedOnTheFly")`, it never gets triggered because the code `$("#DivCreatedOnTheFly")` return `NULL` when it is first interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on()` this way -

```
$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',"#DivCreatedOnTheFly",function(event){
    alert("Click On New Stuff");
});
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, great answer. It works, but #DivCreatedOnTheFly gets created twice . Can this be fixed? Thanks! Si

Comment: You are appending new `div` only *once* , are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, the div must not appear twice, but only once. My code is $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',function(){
 var s = '<div id="DivCreatedOnTheFly" class="Reload">New Stuff</div>' ;
 $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append(s);
});


$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',"#DivCreatedOnTheFly",function(event){
    alert("Click On New Stuff");
});

Comment: instead of append try this - `$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").html(s)`

Comment: Hi Mohammad, $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").html(s) replaces ... I figured out a way using if($("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").length == 0){$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append(s);}, but it's not really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

you may put the events in the `$(document).load(function(){ });`

or after loading the elements dynamically (with callback...)

you code will be something like this:

```
<script>

$(document).load(function(){
    $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',function(){
        var s = '<div id="DivCreatedOnTheFly">New Stuff</div>'  ;
        $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append(s);
        // Code below works fine as expected, 
        // but is nested and is hard to read / debug
        // $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").on('click', 
        //   function(){alert("Click On New Stuff");});
    });

    // The code below fails, 
    // it operate on $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly"), 
    // that doesn't exist when the page is loaded

    $("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").on('click',function(event){alert("Click On New Stuff");}); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for this, but you can also add the functionality on creation of the element. Just wrap the creation of the element in the jQuery function, to create a jQuery object.

```
$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click',function(){
    var $s = $('<div id="DivCreatedOnTheFly">New Stuff</div>');

    $s.on('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });

    $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append($s);
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ruCVy/).

Comment: Great, but I'd rather reduce nesting to it's minimum. Si

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their contributions. Here's the result so far. I hope it will help eventhough it's not as elegant as I would have liked it to be.

http://jsfiddle.net/siba/z7Xcx/2/

```
$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click', function () {
    var s = '<div id="DivCreatedOnTheFly" class="Reload">New Stuff</div>';

    // the 'if' test prevents the div to appear twice

    if ($("#DivCreatedOnTheFly").length == 0) {
        $("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").append(s);
    }

});


$("#ExistsWhenDocIsLoaded").on('click', "#DivCreatedOnTheFly", function (event) {
    alert("Click On New Stuff");
});
```